# Rails/jquery mobile renders a blank page in response to render nothing. How can I suppress that?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

In my view when a radio button is clicked, the answer is posted to the database and there is no need to render anything, but I am getting a 406 message.

application.js:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    return false;
});
```

controller:

```
  def update_result
    ...
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag update_result_answers_path, 'data-ajax' => false do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`406` means that the server understood and processed the request, but the response from server is in a form that the client cannot understand.

You should try:

```
head :ok
```

`render :nothing` has similar meaning to `head :ok`. They both send `200`, except `head :ok` allows you send more http headers back. It's useful for ajax requests where all you want to send back to the browser is an acknowledgment that the request was completed. On `complete callback`, you could update the UI to display it has done successfully.

Comment: +1 for the info. That removes the error. So did the new form syntax i posted. However... jquery mobile still renders a blank page.

Comment: `head :ok` means that it returns only `200` response code back. What do you want to do after the server responds?

Comment: render nothing... update the database only... now it is jumping to a new blank page

Comment: i will have to do a search on how to, "On complete callback, you could update the UI to display it has done successfully." I'll see what I can find.